# Como saber qual tab esta selecionada

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho a seguinte situação

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">                               
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">         
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#1">1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#2">2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#3">3</a></li>               
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="1" class="tab-pane tab tab-label fade in active">
            <button>1</button>
        </div>

        <div id="2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <button>2</button>    
        </div>          

        <div id="3" class="tab-pane fade">
            <button>3</button>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <center><button name="qual_tab">Qual TAB esta selecionada</button></center>
</div>
```

Gostaria de apertar o botão "QUAL_TAB" e saber qual TAB esta ativa.
Não faço a mínima ideia de como proceder.

Colocar no on click do botão algo do HTML???
Colocar no on click do botão algo do javascript???
Ou outro procedimento que não vejo no momento??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize jquery para isso(Mas também pode ser feito com javascript puro), adicione o jquery na pagina:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">                               
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">         
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#1">1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#2">2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#3">3</a></li>               
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="1" class="tab-pane tab tab-label fade in active">
            <button>1</button>
        </div>

        <div id="2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <button>2</button>    
        </div>          

        <div id="3" class="tab-pane fade">
            <button>3</button>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <center><button id="qual_tab" name="qual_tab">Qual TAB esta selecionada</button></center>
</div>
```

Repare que adicionei o id 'qual_tab' no botão, então através do evento clique ele busca a div que esta com a class active, pega o seu id e mostra em um alert.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#qual_tab').click(function(){
    var tab = $('.tab-content .active').attr('id');
    alert(tab);
  });
});
//Pegando o indice
$(".tab-content div").each(function( index ) {
    if($( this ).attr('class').indexOf('active') != -1){
    alert("Indice: " + index);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: valeu mesmo.. PERFEITO :) Voto mas que merecido :). Uma questão agora.  Se eu tiver mais de um grupo de tab-content?? como devo referenciar para pegar as tabs de um ou de outro?? Abraços :)

Comment: Pra que jQuery? JS puro dá conta e fica até mais legível.

Comment: Eu acho mais fácil utilizar jquery @LINQ, mas isso é questão de opinião.

Comment: @Wictor Chaves Uma outra questão.. qual seria o attr para pegar o indice?? Sabe onde consigo ler alguma referencia sobre isso (nav nav-tab)?? :)

Comment: @LINQ Como seria com JS?? Poderia dar uma luz??:) Sempre é bom saber mais :)

Comment: @RicardoM.Souza Posso, 1 minuto que eu mostro

Comment: @RicardoM.Souza Pronto, criei uma resposta e deixei uma observação nela, me avise quando ver.

Comment: @WictorChaves Sim, é questão de opinião, mas do jeito que tu pôs na pergunta parece que a única forma viável de fazer é usando jQuery. Foi só um comentário sobre isto mesmo, não é nenhuma crítica pelo uso da biblioteca. Até porque o bootstrap requer jQuery então...

Comment: @RicardoM.Souza coloquei pegando o índice

Comment: @LINQ coloquei uma observação, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @Wictor Chaves Muito obrigado pela atenção. :) Abraços :)

Answer (score 3):

Solução sem jQuery — o que acaba sendo inútil já que o AP usa *bootstrap* e o mesmo precisa do jQuery para funcionar. Estou postando a pedido do AP mesmo.

```js
document.getElementById('qual_tab').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var tab = document.querySelector('.tab-content .active');
  console.log(`Id da tab selecionada: ${tab.id}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">                               
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">         
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#1">1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#2">2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#3">3</a></li>               
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="1" class="tab-pane tab tab-label fade in active">
            <button>1</button>
        </div>

        <div id="2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <button>2</button>    
        </div>          

        <div id="3" class="tab-pane fade">
            <button>3</button>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <center><button id="qual_tab" name="qual_tab">Qual TAB esta selecionada?</button></center>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito maneiro mesmo.. Com sua resposta pude aprender tambem como declarar os scripts para poder colocar no https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask# , Agora a mesma duvida que perguntei para o  Wictor Chaves: Qual o atributo para retornar o indice ta tab?? ${tab.???} . E se a página contiver mais de um tab-content??? como proceder?? :) mais uma vez.. Obrigado :)

Comment: @RicardoM.Souza As Tabs não têm índices, você teria que controlar manualmente ou capturar o índice da `li` dentro da lista (`ul`). Se a página tiver mais de um tab-content é só você diferenciá-los por uma classe ou id e depois trocar o selector dentro de `querySelector`. Por exemplo, `querySelector('.tab1 .tab-content .active')'` e assim por diante.

Comment: Valeu mesmo.. Obrigado pela atenção :) abraços